# "Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found"

Tags: laravel, charts

Please note that, I'm using rappasoft updated boilerplate Laravel 5.8 and I'm using your installation steps but it's giving me this error message:

> Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts' not found

Answer (score 0):

they forgot to add install charts dependency through composer try this

```
composer require consoletvs/charts
```

this will install your missing dependency